# Create R Windows Binary from .tar.gz linux

Tags: r, cross-compiling

This is sort of related to a previous post of mine.  I have the need to use the bigmemory library on my 32bit Windows PC to do some ugly matrix calculations.  Unfortunately, it appears that the maintainers have temporarily ceased production of Windows binaries.  I have Ubuntu on my home PC.  I would really like to take the .tar.gz file and build it into a Windows binary that I can actually run at work.  I realize there are more efficient ways, like installing RTools on the Windows device.  However, our IT keeps our admin rights on lockdown, so I can never edit my `PATH` enviro variable.  Could anyone provide some general guidance for doing this?  Are there any tools I need to install on my Ubuntu PC above and beyond R?

I found similar questions, but nothing that thoroughly answered my questions.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the package source is incompatible with current versions of R, you could use the R project's [win-builder site](http://win-builder.r-project.org/) to build a Windows binary. Quoting from the linked site, win-builder is a service:

> intended for useRs who do not have Windows available for checking and building Windows binary packages.

As a convenience, Hadley Wickham's **devtools** package includes a utility function, `build_win()`, that you can use for this purpose. From `?build_win`:

> Works by building source package, and then uploading to http://win-builder.r-project.org/>.  Once building is complete you'll receive a link to the built package in the email address listed in the maintainer field.  It usually takes around 30 minutes.

Comment: ... but this probably isn't going to work in any case, because the `bigmemory` package doesn't have a binary on CRAN in the first place (but does have a source package and MacOS binaries, so it's not e.g. a licensing problem). I strongly suspect that there are *good reasons* that the maintainers don't make Windows binaries, and that dealing with this could be a fairly big pain in the butt ...

Comment: However,I am not listed as the maintainer.  The bigmemory package was built and maintained by others.  I'm not sure how to edit the maintainer field in the package, or if this would be appropriate given that I am not the maintainer.

Comment: if you want to try this (I don't think it will work -- see previous comment), you should (1) unpack the `tar.gz` file (`tar zxf ...`); (2) edit the `Maintainer` field of the `DESCRIPTION` file in any text editor of your choice; (3) re-pack the tar (`tar xcf ...`)

Comment: Fair point, Ben.  They indicate there were issues with the `BH` package that `bigmemory` depends on.

Comment: I figure the worst that could happen is that it does install in Windows and it runs abysmally.  At which point I will never use it again!

Comment: @BenBolker -- Agreed. I just came back here to note +/- the same thing (although I've got limited experience of whether compiled packages can fail some of CRAN's checks, but still be practically useful). Do you happen to know what `r-oldrel-windows-ix86+x86_64` (one of the architectures referenced on [bigmemory's check results page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_bigmemory.html)) is, and how it differs from `r-release-windows-ix86+x86_64` [included (e.g.) here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_ACCLMA.html)?

Comment: For example, Jeffrey Horner [no longer maintains Windows binaries of RMySQL](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RMySQL), but when I compile from source on my own Windows box, it works just fine...

Comment: `oldrel` will be for an old release (probably 2.15.x) vs. `r-release` (3.0.x)

Comment: BTW, I'm running R 2.15.2 on my Windows PC.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has four sets of environment variables (system, user, volatile and process sets). The first three sets are stored in the registry but the process set is not so even if they have locked down the registry its typically still possible to set the process environment variables (including the PATH) in a local process, i.e. on a temporary basis, so you might double check your assumptions that you can't modify anything.  Its more likely that you can't modify the system variables and registry but can still modify the set in your local process.  To check this from the Windows cmd line enter this:

```
set mytest=123
set mytest
```

and if the second line shows that `mytest` has the value `123` then you likely have all the permissions you need.

Furthermore anything you need to set is all handled automatically for you by `R.bat` in the [batchfiles distribution](http://batchfiles.googlecode.com) so you don't have to set anything yourself.

Just ensure that Rtools and R are installed into the standard locations (you can tell them to skip the setting of any registry keys during the installation process), ensure `R.bat` is on your path or in current directory and run:

```
R.bat CMD INSTALL mypackage.tar.gz
```

without setting environment variables, registry keys or path.

If that does not work try `Rpathset.bat` also from the batchfiles which is not automatic like `R.bat` but on the other hand is extremely flexible since you must modify the SET statments in it to whatever you want.

There is a PDF document that comes with the batchfiles which gives more info.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the info.  I will have to test it out.  My assumption about not being able to set the `PATH` variable comes from the following:  First, upon installation of RTools, when I tried to add my `\R\\bin` to the `PATH`, it wouldn't let me and I had to abort the installation.  Second, I installed without doing so and then tried to go into the the `Control Panel\System\...` and the `EDIT` and `ADD` buttons under Environmental Variables was greyed out.  I like the R.bat idea.  It seems much more parsimonious than trying to hack together a Windows binary.

Comment: @Jeremy, Its understandable that those facilities would be problematic as they use the system environment variables and therefore require registry access.

Comment: The best solution, of course, would be for me to use Linux...geez, how many times I've said that before!  I'm going to try your solution and Josh's solution at work on Tuesday.

Comment: @Jeremy, You can have permissions problems on Linux too.

Comment: I was able to intall the R.bat file.  I downloaded `bigmemory_4.4.3.tar.gz` and a few of the dependencies.  When I ran from the CMD prompt `R.bat CMD INSTALL bigmemory_4.4.3.tar.gz`, I received the error Warning: invalid package.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Jeremy, I believe bigmemory is a UNIX only package.  Try the ff  or mmap package and note that CRAN has a .zip file for them so you won't need to biuld from source.